# Getting 502 Gateway Error even though there is no error and execution is completed

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, httprequest

Getting 502 Gateway Error even though there is no error and execution is completed

In the .Net MVC I am creating a http request to `fetch huge amount of data`,
then render it using .Net MVC View.

```
HttpRequestMessage httpReq = new HttpRequestMessage();
httpReq.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
httpReq.RequestUri = new Uri("www.SomeWorkingAPI.com");

cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
HttpResponseMessage httpResp = await this.HttpClient.SendAsync(httpReq, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
string content = await httpResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  JToken resp = JToken.Parse(content);
}

...

return View(model);
```

Execution gets completed but on web page it shows `502 Bad Gateway`.
I have tried adding logs and catching error, there is not error thrown.
Note that it is not happening for small amount of data.
Let me know if I am missing some configuration.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am facing a similar issue.